# Get notified when a process or application is killed/forcekilled?

Tags: cocoa, macos, process, macos-carbon

I am trying to monitor if certain application has killed, crashed, force killed on system. How can I get such notifications on Mac.

What is the common approach to implement such design?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to know?  If it's your app that you want to monitor, put the app in as a service and let the system restarts it.

Comment: I am trying to monitor other processes running on system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically check if a process is running on Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518160/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-mac)

Comment: No its not duplicate of it. I dont know the process name. I want a service kind of thing which can notify if any process on system has been has killed, crashed, force killed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2050/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the common approach, although probably not exactly what you're looking for, is to periodically poll your processes.  For instance:

```
ps -A | grep 'someIndentifingString'
```

If this doesn't return anything, your process is gone.

This won't, though, tell you if it was caused by a crash, force kill etc., so I'm not sure that it completely meets your needs.

Comment: Polling approach may work. But I am not trying to monitor my process, I am trying to monitor other processes running on system. Something which activity monitor does(not exactly).

Comment: 'ps -A' should give you all of the processes running on the machine, not just your own.  EDIT - just saw your comment above - sounds like you're looking for if *any* processes is killed, not a specific process - if that's true then you're correct - polling won't cut it.