# Detect Wallpaper applications running on os x?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to detect if any Wallpaper type application is running on system and try to close them.

For example, [Mechanical Clock 3D Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mechanical-clock-3d-lite/id448125889?mt=12) for 10.8 is one of the apps which run as wallpaper for system. Is their any way to detect such applications?

Answer (score 0):

This question, [Programmatically check if a process is running on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518160/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-mac), might lead you in the right direction. Essentially you find a list of currently running processes and check if that application name exists within it.

Comment: Question is not about how to find a process. Its about detecting application which are like wallpaper/screensaver running on your desktop.

Comment: I know. The only way you could really detect a wallpaper application is to search all processes against a list of known wallpaper apps.

Comment: But thats not generic at all and its bound to fail. May be their is something wallpaper application does with layer or position or any clue which confirms it as wallpaper app. For sure we have to Iterate list of apps. But instead of comparing their names, I was wondering if their is any property?

Comment: As far as I know there is no property. Sorry about that :(