# Objective C code for background processes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsarray, nsworkspace

I have used NSApplication and NSWorkspace to get a list of running applications.

But it is only giving me the applications that are active from the administrator and not the root processes that run in the background.

I want to get a list of all running processes and keep updating that list as soon as a new process spawns.

I prefer not to use `NSTask` and parsing the output.

Is there a fix for this?

```
NSArray * runningapps = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications];
```

Comment: I think following one is useful. [Programmatically check if a process is running on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518160/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-mac)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Perhaps you don't need what you are asking for. Are you trying to check whether a process you spawned is running?

Comment: I want to know if any process spawns in the background. I was able to do it for applications but the root processes are not being listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the website given below : 
https://github.com/objective-see/ProcInfo

Answer (score 1):

To have access to the list of root processes you need to do stuff very similar to what the `ps` command does. If you want to go at it, go study the source code of this tool:

https://opensource.apple.com/source/adv_cmds/adv_cmds-172/ps/

However, as you can see, this is not easy. Thus, if you don't want to reinvent the wheel, I'd just parse the output of `ps` command with `grep` or you will need to write your own code to do what you want.

Comment: After all, there is no need to be root to list all the processes. I just managed to build and run ps from Apple's source code in the lldb and it works without being root.

Answer (score 1):

The way I achieve this is simply by iterating through every process identifier (to a certain extent). (This does require higher permissions though like sudo to get info on root processes)

```
#include <sys/proc_info.h>
#define SHOW_ZOMBIES 0

extern int proc_pidinfo(int pid, int flavor, uint64_t arg, user_addr_t buffer, uint32_t buffersize);

void iterateProcesses() {

    pid_t maxPID = 100000;
    for (pid_t cPID = 0; cPID < maxPID+1; cPID++) {
        if (!(getpgid(cPID)>=0)) {continue;} // Skips if PID is invalid

        // Now we can get some information 

        struct proc_taskallinfo info;
        proc_pidinfo(cPID, PROC_PIDTASKALLINFO, SHOW_ZOMBIES, (user_addr_t)&info, sizeof(struct proc_taskallinfo));

        char *proc_name = (char *)info.pbsd.pbi_name;
        printf("Found a Process Called %s With a PID of %d\n",proc_name,cPID);

        // Now if we want to do some more stuff with it we can get its task.

        task_t task;
        kern_return_t ret = task_for_pid(current_task(),cPID,&task);
        if (ret != KERN_SUCCESS) {continue;} // Can't access task. skip

        // Now we have the task. We can do some stuff with it...
        task_suspend(task);
    }
}
```

Anyways I hope this helps someone. ;)

Comment: This was really useful and was pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! However, I found that this code leaked memory on each iteration. I solved the memory leak by replacing the relevant line of code with this: proc_pidinfo(cPID, PROC_PIDTASKALLINFO, (uint64_t)0, &info, sizeof(info));

Comment: ahh ye my bad, thats good that you got some use outta it :P