# prevent macOS app from having multiple instances running simultaneously (launch executable file in terminal)

Tags: xcode, macos

I set LSMultipleInstancesProhibited to YES, but if launch executable file(/Contents/MacOS/) in terminal, the macOS app can be run multiplely. for example: first terminal can run first executable file, second terminal can run second executable file. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is related to MacOS. SO is for programming. Also, your question doesn't have details. People who read your question won't know what you are looking for. Give details, be specific.

Comment: Running from terminal bypasses LaunchServices. That’s why, nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the information of your own app and check if there is already running instance in the system.
[Programmatically check if a process is running on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518160/programmatically-check-if-a-process-is-running-on-mac)